# Detect UISearchToken selection in UISearchTextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uisearchtextfield, uisearchtoken

This should be simple perhaps I am missing it somewhere...

- **How can I detect when a user selects / highlights a `UISearchToken` currently presented in a `UISearchTextField`?**

---

Here is a photo showing how I am trying to *detect when* the user selects a token: i.e. the "second" token was selected here

[image]

---

For reference, I am developing this in Swift on iOS 16+.

Upon the user hitting the "return" key, I am adding tokens to the text field:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if addTokensOnReturn && !text!.isEmpty {
        insertToken(UISearchToken(icon: nil, text: text!), at: tokens.endIndex)
        text = ""
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```